# How to split letter and digit apart of a string in perl?

Tags: regex, string, perl, split, substitution

Split the string using split() and make an array from that string such that words and numbers are apart.

I know that lookahead and lookbehind need to be used for zero width splitting and so i used that.

```
$string = 'A1BB22CCC333DDDD';
@string = split(/(?=\d+)|(?<=\d+)/,$string);
print "@string";
```

Expectation:

```
A 1 BB 22 CCC 333 DDDD
```

But results:

> Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex m/(?=\d+)|(?<=\d+)/ at jdoodle.pl line 2.
>
> Command exited with non-zero status 255.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a pattern like `/(\d+)/` to split the string.

The pattern contains a capturing group; as explained in [perldoc split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

> If the PATTERN contains capturing groups, then for each separator, an additional field is produced for each substring captured by a group (in the order in which the groups are specified, as per backreferences);

Consider:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string = "A1BB22CCC333DDDD";
my @result = split /(\d+)/, $string;
print "$_\n" for @result;
```

Yields:

```
A
1
BB
22
CCC
333
DDDD
```

---

The above solution will return a leading empty element if the string does start with a digit. To avoid this, you can adapt the expression as follows:

```
my @result = grep length, split /(\d+)/, $string;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:**

There's no need to check how many digits are on each side of the split point, so you could simply replace `\d+` with `\d` to avoid the error you are getting. But then you'd notice the second problem with your solution: You aren't just splitting between digits and non-digits; you are splitting between two digits as well. Fixed:

```
my @parts = split /(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)/, $string;
```

**Option 2:**

Text captured by the pattern passed to `split` are returned, giving us an alternative solution using `split`.

```
my @parts = grep length, split /(\d+)/, $string;
```

The `grep` handles the case where `$string` starts with a digit.

You get in a situation where you need to fix the output of `split` like this when the thing on which you are splitting isn't actually a separator. This should tell you that `split` isn't the appropriate tool in that situation.

**Option 3:**

A simple regex match will do here.

```
my @parts = $string =~ /\d+|\D+/g;
```